# filter a Pandas dataframe for added unique values

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I would like to know what I need to do in order to filter a dataframe, keeping unique values of `Name` column, adding values from `Value` column and adding a new column for counting appearances of each `Name`

what I have is this:

```
     Name Type  Value
0   apple    A      1
1  banana    B      3
2   apple    A      2
3    pear    P      4
4   apple    A      6
5  carrot    C      3
6  banana    B      2
```

and I want to filter it into this:

```
     Name Type  AddedValue  Occurrences
0   apple    A      9       3
1  banana    B      5       2
2    pear    P      4       1
3  carrot    C      3       1
```

How can I do it? I've tried conceive a `.join` method with a `where` condition set, but I cannot make it work and I'm sure that the problem is that I'm trying to translate pythonic thinking where there surely is a panda instruction which solves my problem with an elegant vector operation or something like that

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Try `groupby` method:

```
df.groupby(["Name","Type"]).agg(["count","sum"])
```

Result:

```
            Value    
            count sum
Name   Type          
apple  A        3   9
banana B        2   5
carrot C        1   3
pear   P        1   4
```

However if You want to flatten columns/index use:

```
df2 = df.groupby(["Name","Type"]).agg(["count","sum"]).reset_index(drop=False)

df2.columns = [' '.join(col).strip() for col in df2.columns.values]
```

Output:

```
     Name Type  Value count  Value sum
0   apple    A            3          9
1  banana    B            2          5
2  carrot    C            1          3
3    pear    P            1          4
```

Even more elegant solution thanks to @piRSquared:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Name', 'Type']).Value.agg([('AddedValue', 'sum'), ('Occurences', 'count')]).reset_index(drop=False)
```

Output:

```
     Name Type  AddedValue  Occurences
0   apple    A           9           3
1  banana    B           5           2
2  carrot    C           3           1
3    pear    P           4           1
```

Comment: `df.groupby(['Name', 'Type']).Value.agg([('AddedValue', 'sum'), ('Occurences', 'count')])`

Comment: @ipj thanks a lot!!

I really would like to understand why .reset_index avoids grouping / using name and type as indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just like ipj has answered you can try the groupby method in Pandas [Groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

```
df = df.groupby(["Name","Type"]).agg(["count","sum"])
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
df = df.rename({"count": "AddedValue", "sum": "Occurrences"}, axis=1)
```